# Calling uber API

Tags: api, uber-api

When I call ubers API from my front end, the call gets blocked with the following error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. However, when I call from a node js application the call goes through just fine. The code is the exact same. See below:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price",
headers: {
  Authorization: "Token " + uberServerToken
},
success: function(result) {
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [CORS policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enforced by the browser. For cross domain requests the server must include a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This is likely on purpose as you should never include a server tonken in your client code. For the client you should be using a bearer token. Take a look at the [Uber API documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api).

Since the server is at your own control you're free to make API requests to anywhere.

Comment: This is correct. You can configure the origin uri in the developer dashboard for your application.